# The Number() function adds 1 to the numeric result by converting a string to a number

Tags: javascript, string-formatting

I wanted to convert the **string** `'9333852702227987'` into a **number** with the help of the `Number()` function when I realized that the output was plus one.

I tried using other `methods` to convert the `string value` that contains the mentioned number into a `number value`, but I still faced the same problem.

```
let convertToString = function (num1) {
    console.log(Number(num1))
    console.log(parseInt(num1))
    console.log(num1 * 1)
    console.log(Math.round(num1))
    console.log(Math.floor(num1))
    console.log(Math.ceil(num1))
    console.log('All results of the ways to convert a string into a number are wrong!!!')
};

convertToString('9333852702227987')


// The result of all of them is: 9333852702227988
```

Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: Hint: just type that number 9333852702227987 in the search box above ;)

Comment: ^^^ or `9333852702227987 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`